# How can I create a variable using the names of other variables/in an array or macro? (in sas)

Tags: arrays, macros, sas

I need to create a character variable that has the values of other variable names. I have a marco that defines a number of variables as such:

```
%macro all (marconame=);
%macroname(cat=tabby,
           dog=golden);
%macroname(cat=black,
           dog=beagle); 

%mend all;
```

So I can call the marco for each variable (&cat., &dog.), and i have an array of each of the variables (&cats. = tabby black).

What I need to do is  be able to print like this:

```
Cat     Dog
tabby   golden
black   beagle
```

I tried using a put statement and creating empty datasets with each array then transposing but some of the cat types repeat so it drops one version.

Basically I want to write something like:
Cat2="&cat.";

and then loop through the marco but I get an error.

Comment: Are you typing the lists into the code or is there some input where this information already exists?

Comment: Aside from my answer, your question shows that you really need to read something like `The Little Book of SAS` or similar - your terminology doesn't make any sense (there is no such thing as a macro variable array, for example).

Comment: What kind of value are you going to pass to %all macro (as argument marconame=)? Name of another macro?

Answer (score 0):

You are likely confusing the concept of 'macro' with 'procedure/subroutine' from other languages.  Macro is not a subroutine or procedure, though it can be sort of like a function sometimes.  In general, macros simply produce normal SAS code that is executed normally, as if you'd typed it yourself, just faster to produce than all that typing.

What you need to do ultimately is construct this datastep:

```
data want;
cat='tabby';
dog='golden';
output;
cat='black';
dog='beagle';
output;
run;
```

So what the macro will want to consist of is three lines: cat assignment, dog assignment, and output.  So remove those three lines and all of their repeats, and replace each repeat with a macro call.

```
data want;
%dogcat(cat=tabby,dog=golden);
%dogcat(cat=black,dog=beagle);
run;
```

Note that the data and run statements are still there.

Now define the macro.

```
%macro dogcat(cat=,dog=);
cat="&cat."; *important, double quote = lets macro variable resolve, single does NOT.;
dog="&dog.";
output;
%mend dogcat;
```

Now just move the macro above your code (or at least, execute it first), and it will run as you intend.

You could certainly make a more general macro:

```
%macro animal(animal=,type=);
&animal.="&type.";
%mend animal;

%macro dogcat(dog=,cat=);
%animal(animal=dog,type=&dog);
%animal(animal=cat,type=&cat);
output;
%mend dogcat;
```

Of course that's probably over the top since datasets have to have the same variables defined on each row - unless you're planning to have lots of variables and only populate certain ones, in which case it might be useful; or you want a vertical dataset.